# Led blanking while the DIO_Read is LOW and work well while DIO_Read is HIGH

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, atmega, input

I'm trying to read digital 24v in MCU so I used a voltage regulator to step it down to 5v then I got the 5v to pull down resistor with a transistor like that

[image]

then I get the V out to the MCU pin which is DIO_read and some LEDs to other DIO_write,

```
int main(void) {

DIO_Inti();
char x=0;

while (1) 
{
    x=DIO_ReadPin(PIND0);
    if(x==HIGH)
    {
        DIO_WritePin(PINB1,HIGH);
        DIO_WritePin(PINB2,HIGH);
        DIO_WritePin(PIND6,HIGH);
        DIO_WritePin(PIND5,HIGH);
        DIO_WritePin(PIND3,HIGH);
    }
    else if(x==LOW)
    {
        DIO_WritePin(PINB1,LOW);
        DIO_WritePin(PINB2,LOW);
        DIO_WritePin(PIND6,LOW);
        DIO_WritePin(PIND5,LOW);
        DIO_WritePin(PIND3,LOW);
    }
    _delay_ms(100);
}

return 0;
```

}

when the Vout is high the LEDs work well, when the Vout is low the LEDs blink randomly I don't know how that happens with the pulldown resistor.

Here is the DIO_ReadPin function

```
DIO_PinVolt_t DIO_ReadPin(DIO_Pin_t pin)
{

DIO_PinVolt_t volt = LOW;

// PORTB
if (pin >= PINB0 && pin <= PINB7)
{
    volt = GET_BIT(PINB, (pin));
} // PORTC
else if (pin >= PINC0 && pin <= PINC6)
{
    volt = GET_BIT(PINC, (pin - PINC0));
} // PORTD
else if (pin >= PIND0 && pin <= PIND7)
{
    volt = GET_BIT(PIND, (pin - PIND0));
}

return volt;
}
```

can anyone help to explain and solve that?

Comment: What voltages you get on the MCU pin? Have you measured anything about the circuit with a multimeter? Or an oscilloscope?

Comment: Yes I measured it. it's 4.8v when the input is high and around 0.23v when the input is low

Comment: That info should be in the question. OK, so what voltages there are on the input or base? What is the source of the 24V signal, is it perhaps coming from on/off switch so it is floating instead of 0V, when there is no 24V there? What if you poke a finger to the VIN or base, will LEDs blink?

Comment: those voltage is in the input of mcu. it's a digital 24v signal and float if no 24v signal but I added a pull down resistor on the mcu pin

Comment: @abdallazakaria - Hi, Currently your question breaks the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) material copied/adapted from elsewhere. To comply with that rule, please [edit] the question & add the **name** of the PDF / video / webpage (etc.) which is the source of the original schematic, and its **link**. Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the signal input to transistor is not 24V and 0V, but 24V and indeterminate floating voltage, possibly with a long wire connected to base acting as an antenna for receiving electrical noise.

You need to pull the transistor base down to 0V with a resistor to prevent even a small disturbance from amplifying the base current to collector (emitter) current and pulling the MCU pin high.